# Using Yii2 TimestampBehavior returns 'created_at' doesn't have a default value error

Tags: yii2

Trying to use the Yii2 `TimestampBehavior` but when saving it will return a `doesn't have default value` error.

The values are not required in the rules. The DB column is a `INT(11)`.
As I needed to save several rows I use `batchInsert()` for this.

When I add a the value with `time()` it will save everything to the DB.

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return [
       'timestamp' => [
           'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
           'attributes' => [
               ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_at',
               ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
           ],
           'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
       ],
       'blameable' => [
           'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
           'createdByAttribute' => 'created_by',
           'updatedByAttribute' => 'updated_by',
        ],
   ];
}

Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert( 'table_cms',
     [
        //all fields but not the timestamps
     ],
     [
        //rows here
     ])
     ->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

`batchInsert()` does not support ActiveRecord features, so `TimestampBehavior` has no effect here. `TimestampBehavior` will be used if you call `save()`. In your case you need to pass timestamp manually.

`doesn't have default value` probably means that you're using MySQL in strict mode - it will warn you if you will try to add record without specifying all fields without default values.

Comment: Okay I was afraid that batchInsert did not support the behavior, well I will do it manually. Thanks for the info :-)